# Getting error when I click on models in mlflow

Tags: sqlite, mlflow

I am using SQLite as back-end for ml-flow and I have registered a model. I got registered successful as output. but whenever I click on models I am getting below error. Not sure why I am getting this.

INVALID_PARAMETER_VALUE: Invalid clause(s) in filter string: 'name', 'ilike', ''%%''. Expected search filter with single comparison operator. e.g. name='myModelName'

Comment: what is the name of the model? I suspect that name contains some characters that aren't handled well by the SQL backend

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a bug in an earlier version of the sqlparse module. I had the same problem. Updated:

sqlparse==0.3.1 (was 0.3.0)

SQLAlchemy==1.3.13 (was 1.3.3)

and it solved the problem.